# How to get all keys in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I need to get address, lat and lng:

```
let Orders= [{
  pedido: this.listAddress[0].address,
  lat: this.listAddress[0].lat,
  lng: this.listAddress[0].lng
}]
```

But in that way, i only get the first item, i need to get all datas dynamically

```
0: {address:"test 00", lat:"00", lng:"00"}
1: {address:"test 01", lat:"01", lng:"01"}
2: {address:"test 02", lat:"01", lng:"02"}
3: {address:"test 03", lat:"01", lng:"03"}
```

Comment: Arrays don't have keys, objects do. What you have is a single object in an array. If there will only be one object, the array is an unnecessary wrapper. And where is the code for `listAddress`?

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const orders = listAddress.map(list => {
   return ({
     pedido: list.address,
     lat: list.lat,
     lng: list.lng
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const orders = listAddress.map(list => {
   return ({
      pedido: list.address,
      lat: list.lat,
      lng: list.lng
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming listAddress is an array of object, you need to iterate over the array in order to get every element

```
let order = listAddress.map(el => {
 return {
      pedido: el.address,
      lat: el.lat,
      lng: el.lng
   }
})
```

Comment: Running .map over array and pushing items in different array variable is wrong practice. .map it self returns an array, so just storing returned output in new variable will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you're looking for something like below. Take a look

```
let Orders = this.listAddress.map(la => ({
    address: la.address,
    lat: la.lat,
    lng: la.lng
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const order = {
    0: {address:"test 00", lat:"00", lng:"00"},
    1: {address:"test 01", lat:"01", lng:"01"},
    2: {address:"test 02", lat:"01", lng:"02"},
    3: {address:"test 03", lat:"01", lng:"03"},
}


Object.values(order).forEach(obj =>{
    const {address, lat, lng} = obj;
    console.log(address, lat, lng)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try Array.**map** method in JS

So the usage is like this

```js
const inputArray = [
   {address:"test 00", lat:"00", lng:"00"},
   {address:"test 01", lat:"01", lng:"01"},
   {address:"test 02", lat:"02", lng:"02"},
]

const outputArray = inputArray.map( item => (
      {
         pedido: item.address,
         lat: item.lat,
         lng: item.lng,
      }
   )
)

console.log(outputArray) // [Object { pedido: "test 00", lat: "00", lng: "00" }, Object { pedido: "test 01", lat: "01", lng: "01" }, Object { pedido: "test 02", lat: "02", lng: "02" }]
```

Learn more here [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)